# How can I render dynamic QR codes in a slider using Django data?

Tags: javascript, django

Help, please
I need to render in slider dynamic qr-codes.
I receive data from admin model (Django). It work for text, but link for qrs are the same.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">


 <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for a in advertising %} 
      <div class="carousel-item carousel-item1 {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}" data-bs-interval="2000">
        
        <h3 class="install-app">{{a.advertising_text}}</h3>
        <div class="qr-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
     {% endfor %}

    </div>
  </div>
```

And script
qrCodeMaker();

```
function qrCodeMaker(qr) {
 
   const qrs = document.querySelectorAll(".qr-wrapper");
   console.log('qrs', qrs)
    qrs.forEach(function (qr) {


        q = new QRCode(qr, {
        // {% for a in advertising %}
         text: "{{a.URL}}",
        //    {% endfor %} 
         colorDark: "#002F43",
         colorLight: "#F5F7F7"
    } )
    
})
}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when i use this code- in my slider text changes dynamic, but qr-codes render all at the same time, not one on one slide

Comment: Could you please post an image of how it looks with text and an image of how it looks with the qr-codes?

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to comment some Django code in the `qrCodeMaker()` function, but the code is not actually commented: `//` works for commenting Javascript code, but inline comments in Django templates use `{# ... #}`. This means that the for statement is still working, and is adding a `text` field for every element in `advertising`. The first step is to remove completely the code inside the comments (or at least to comment it properly).

When that's done, there's a new problem: you are now accessing `a.URL` outside of the for loop, which means that `a` is not defined. So you need to find another way to access the correct url.

The following code should fix all the issues:

**HTML**

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">


 <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for a in advertising %} 
      <div class="carousel-item carousel-item1 {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}" data-bs-interval="2000">
        
        <h3 class="install-app">{{a.advertising_text}}</h3>
        <div class="qr-wrapper" id="{{a.URL}}"></div>
    </div>
     {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function qrCodeMaker(qr) {
   const qrs = document.querySelectorAll(".qr-wrapper");
   console.log('qrs', qrs)
   qrs.forEach(function (qr) {
        q = new QRCode(qr, {
         text: qr.id,
         colorDark: "#002F43",
         colorLight: "#F5F7F7"
        } )
   })
}
```

Comment: it doesnt influenced. My div is inside for loop in html. So it render qr, but for one item it renders all existing qr's

Comment: Have you removed the comments "// {% for a in advertising %}" and "//    {% endfor %}"? They appear as a comment because the IDE thinks they are javascript code, but that is not the correct way to comment code for Django templates. So Django is still reading that for statement and adding a "text" field for every item "a" in "advertising".

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the problem with the code not properly commented.